# AddThis doesn't share the correct URL to Facebook even with valid OpenGraph tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, addthis

The [AddThis Blog](http://www.addthis.com/blog/2012/09/27/debugging-sharing-to-facebook/) states that Facebook does not honor the "URL to share" specified in the AddThis configuration, and I have followed the instructions to add OpenGraph meta tags to the page whose URL I want to share.

I have confirmed via the Facebook Debugger tool that these tags are valid.

However, if I try to share a password-protected staging URL, it works in Twitter and elsewhere but not Facebook.  Facebook tries to share the login page for my site; I bet it's trying to share the origin page (where I'm trying to share *from*, which is a password-protected internal page, so trying to access it prior to login bounces you to the login page).

How can I get this to work how I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you keep track of changes on the documentation:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381263-addthis-client-api#configuration-sharing

Basically the URL to be shared needs to be configured in the addthis_share object.